# can mod_passenger be used with Geronimo Apache?

Tags: phusion-passenger

Can Phusion Passenger be installed and used with Geronimo?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no.

[Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) currently only works with [Apache httpd](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) and [nginx](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html).

[Apache](http://apache.org/) by the way, is the name of a software foundation and not a specific product. Apache Geronimo and Apache httpd on the other hand are specific products under the umbrella of the ASF.

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer is suspected but wanted to make sure there wasn't someone out there doing it. Yeah, I am quite familiar with Apache foundation. I've been using the web server since NCSA HTTPd.